# Set ActionBar Tabs at bottom in ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

Hello I am noob in Android.

I am using `appcompat` support library to add tabs in `ActionBarActivity`. I have written the code to add but tabs is showing at the top see it in the screenshot. I want to set these `Tabs` that would appear at the bottom.

Any idea why it so ?

```
private ActionBar mActionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // find the action bar
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    // First Tab of the Activity
    ActionBar.Tab mTab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("First Tab").setTabListener(this);
    mActionBar.addTab(mTab);
    mActionBar.selectTab(mTab);

    // Second Tab of the Activity
    mTab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Second Tab").setTabListener(this);
    mActionBar.addTab(mTab);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction) {
    if(tab.getPosition() == 0) {
        fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.container, new FirstFragment());
    } else {
        fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.container, new SecondFragment());
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: you can use page indicator , you can check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22936336/1332870

Comment: you can check [this example](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/BottomTabBar)

Answer (score 9):

You can create your own TabView Bar at any place of screen, for example at bottom
work perfectly for swiching fragments
simple customize view in tags_icon.xml

**It is bottom TabView**

**Main activity Class**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TagsActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String M_CURRENT_TAB = "M_CURRENT_TAB";
    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private String mCurrentTab;

    public static final String TAB_TAGS = "TAB_TAGS";
    public static final String TAB_MAP = "TAB_MAP";
    public static final String TAB_SETTINGS = "TAB_SETTINGS";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.tags_activity);

        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        mTabHost.setup();

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentTab = savedInstanceState.getString(M_CURRENT_TAB);
            initializeTabs();
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(mCurrentTab);
            /*
            when resume state it's important to set listener after initializeTabs
            */
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(listener);
        } else {
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(listener);
            initializeTabs();
        }
    }

    private View createTabView(final int id, final String text) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs_icon, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(id));
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_text);
        textView.setText(text);
        return view;
    }

    /*
    create 3 tabs with name and image
    and add it to TabHost
     */
    public void initializeTabs() {

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TAGS);
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);
            }
        });
        spec.setIndicator(createTabView(R.drawable.tab_tag_drawable, getString(R.string.tab_tags)));
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);

        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_MAP);
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);
            }
        });
        spec.setIndicator(createTabView(R.drawable.tab_map_drawable, getString(R.string.tab_map)));
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);


        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_SETTINGS);
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);
            }
        });
        spec.setIndicator(createTabView(R.drawable.tab_settings_drawable, getString(R.string.tab_settings)));
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);

    }

    /*
    first time listener will be trigered immediatelly after first: mTabHost.addTab(spec);
    for set correct Tab in setmTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag ignore first call of listener
    */
    TabHost.OnTabChangeListener listener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

            mCurrentTab = tabId;

            if (tabId.equals(TAB_TAGS)) {
                pushFragments(SearchFragment.getInstance(), false,
                        false, null);
            } else if (tabId.equals(TAB_MAP)) {
                pushFragments(MapContainerFragment.getInstance(), false,
                        false, null);
            } else if (tabId.equals(TAB_SETTINGS)) {
                pushFragments(SettingsFragment.getInstance(), false,
                        false, null);
            }

        }
    };

/*
Example of starting nested fragment from another fragment:

Fragment newFragment = ManagerTagFragment.newInstance(tag.getMac());
                TagsActivity tAct = (TagsActivity)getActivity();
                tAct.pushFragments(newFragment, true, true, null);
 */
    public void pushFragments(Fragment fragment,
                              boolean shouldAnimate, boolean shouldAdd, String tag) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        if (shouldAnimate) {
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_slide_left_enter,
                    R.animator.fragment_slide_left_exit,
                    R.animator.fragment_slide_right_enter,
                    R.animator.fragment_slide_right_exit);
        }
        ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment, tag);

        if (shouldAdd) {
            /*
            here you can create named backstack for realize another logic.
            ft.addToBackStack("name of your backstack");
             */
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
        } else {
            /*
            and remove named backstack:
            manager.popBackStack("name of your backstack", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            or remove whole:
            manager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
             */
            manager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
        ft.commit();
    }

    /*
    If you want to start this activity from another
     */
    public static void startUrself(Activity context) {
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(context, TagsActivity.class);
        newActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(newActivity);
        context.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString(M_CURRENT_TAB, mCurrentTab);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**tags_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TabHost
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/realtabcontent"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_main_app_gradient"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:background="#EAE7E1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

**tags_icon.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_tab_gradient"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="contentDescription" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tab_icon"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tab_text"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine when I sepratly use it.. but when I use FragmentTabHot... it gives me error...Can you please help me...
Thanks..

Comment: Thanks ... for reply.. Its my mistake.. Its woking..I have upvote your answer.. It really helps me:)

Comment: Nice answer @Flinbor ,Is it possible to implement these tabs in fragment ?

Comment: @SriKanth I think yes, if you will create content of tabs as inner fragmants. And tabs as parent. May cause issues with backstack however.

Comment: @Flinbor How to make the fragments swipable here like view pager ?

Comment: @Prabha1 You can customize ViewPagerAdapter, in adapter override on page selected and set required tab. Also you can take idea how to do it here https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-SlidingTabLayout