# How to make the Xamarin.Forms TabbedPage in Android has the same look as it in iOS

Tags: xamarin

The TabbedPage looks differently between iOS/android.

Is it possible to let the TabbedPage display tabs and icons on the bottom of screen when the app running in android, just like in iOS?

Comment: They are different by design. The android design guidelines are different from the iOS guidelines. It is not the normal way that users are accustomed to. You probably want to reconsider if you want to really do this. But if you really want to do this, you should make a custom renderer and do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23150258/5852062

Comment: @iMarcB Thanks for your comment, the link points to android native code and I wonder if there is a solution using Xamarin.Forms .

Comment: There is as i mentioned in my previous comment. You should use a custom renderer: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/ and then inflate your custom designed layout(like the android one in the blog post) in that custom renderer.

Comment: backing @marc here.  not possible without customer renderer or some such.  in which case  you need to write a lot of code yourself.

Answer (score -1):

To accomplish this you would have to write your own custom Renderer
[link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)

However the link below is an implementation that allows you android to have you tabs look like iOS

https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17743516)

Comment: Maybe I should be putting this link as a comment but I hate finding questions with no answers. Just because the only answer is a link to helpful materials.